# How to add item divider in RecyclerView for specific items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Is it possible to add item dividers in a `RecyclerView` for specific items only? Currently, the item dividers are being applied in between each item. I want to add a divider in the following locations:

- between **Item B** and **Section C**
- between **Item C3** and **Section D**
- between **Item D2** and **Section E**
- between **Item E3** and **Item F1**
- between **Item F1** and **Item G1**

**Current result**

[image: Current result]

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentRV extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public FragmentRV() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initRVAdapter();
    }

    private void initRVAdapter(){
        List<Object> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

        RVItemsAapter itemsListAdapter = new RVItemsAapter(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsListAdapter);

        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item A","Item A description"));
        itemsList.add(new Phonecall("Item B","Item B description"));
        itemsList.add(new SectionHeader("Section C"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item C1","Item C1 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item C2","Item C2 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item C3","Item C3 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SectionHeader("Section D"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item D1","Item D1 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item D2","Item D2 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SectionHeader("Section E"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item E1","Item E1 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item E2","Item E2 description"));
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item E3","Item E3 description")); 
        itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item F1","Item F1 description"));             
        itemsList.add(new Phonecall("Item G1","Item G1 description"));

        itemsListAdapter.setCallSMSFeed(itemsList);
        itemsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I needed a divider between sections, I would try to define a type for section headers in recyclerview adapter class globally:

```
private static final int TYPE_SMS_MESSAGE = 0;
private static final int TYPE_PHONE_CALL = 1;
private static final int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 2;
```

Then I would return a layout with TextView and a divider line below it.

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_SMS_MESSAGE:
            // return a view as you did before
        case TYPE_PHONE_CALL:
            // return a view as you did before
        case TYPE_SECTION_HEADER:
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.section_header_layout, null);
            return new YourRecyclerViewHolder(v);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

To be able to detect and return this layout, you need detect that it is an instance of SectionHeader.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (itemList.get(position) instanceof SectionHeader) {
        return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
    }
    /* return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER if the data in the list is an instance of 
       SectionHeader and other corresponding types as well */
}
```

Hope this would help you to have an idea and make progress on it!
Happy Coding :)

Baki

Comment: I don't want a divider line below the TextView. I want the divider line above the TextView and below the group of items underneath the TextView.

Comment: So as I have mentioned, you can use any custom layout. The adapter will detect that it is a type of SectionHeader and it will return the layout you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to remove all of the dividers like so:

First define your RecyclerView :

`RecyclerView recycle = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);`

and in your activity use this method:

```
recycle.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, 0));
```

Then in your custom adapter you could add divider where you want:

```
itemsList.add(new SMSmessage("Item A","Item A description"));
itemsList.add(new Phonecall("Item B","Item B description"));
itemsList.add(new YourCustomDivider());
itemsList.add(new SectionHeader("Section C"));
```

Comment: Where did you get `YourCustomDivider` from? What code needs to go in that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you can do is in your row.xml layout, create your custom divider and show/ hide it based on the condition in `onBindViewholder()` method

Answer (score -2):

A solutions is write a custom RecyclerView.ItemDecoration and draw the divider only where you want. You should override the onDraw() method where the magic happens.
You can set a custom ItemDecoration in RecyclerView using the code below:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CustomItemDecoration());
```